# Animated canvas error: cannot convert from void to bitmap drawable

Tags: java, android, graphics

I've animated a canvas for my project, but I get an error: 'Cannot convert from void to bitmap drawable'. Where is the fault?

```
BitmapDrawable circle = (BitmapDrawable) canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, (float) (canvas.getHeight()/1.8), 13, black);
```

For the context, this is the complete excerpt of the code

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  

        Paint black = new Paint(Color.BLACK);

        BitmapDrawable circle = (BitmapDrawable) canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, (float) (canvas.getHeight()/1.8), 13, black);
        if (x<0 && y <0) {
            x = this.getWidth()/2;
            y = this.getHeight()/2;
        } else {
            x += xVelocity;
            y += yVelocity;
            if ((x > this.getWidth() - circle.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
                xVelocity = xVelocity*-1;
            }
            if ((y > this.getHeight() - circle.getBitmap().getHeight()) || (y < 0)) {
                yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
            }
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(circle.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  

        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);


    }
```

Comment: @MikeM. How do i solve it then?

Comment: I actually just tried to animate my canvas and thought it would work this way. Do you know how i need to change it?

Comment: Yes i actually want it to bounce straight from left to right starting in the middle, but i tried it at first with random bouncing. Do i need to change it? I just get the error at the color part

Comment: The error is in `BitmapDrawable circle = (BitmapDrawable) canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, (float) (canvas.getHeight()/1.8), 13, black);` - black is underlined and it returns the error i mentioned in the question. I case i delete Color.black the contructor is incomplete, because it expects (float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint)

Comment: If i delete the BitmapDrawable part so there's only `canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, (float) (canvas.getHeight()/1.8), 13, black);` it says that the method drawCircle would be undefined for the type AnimatedView

Comment: My fault, i missunderstood your hint! The error is gone. But of course now i get a new error in the line `canvas.drawBitmap(circle.getBitmap(), x, y, null);` because i put the 'BitmapDrawable circle =...' out. What do i replace the 'circle' parts with?

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. You said i need to delete it in case it should bounce around - do i need it in case it should bounce straight horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @MikeM. I did it as you told me to, I have no errors anymore, but a black screen, even when i change the color of my canvas

Comment: So do i need to change the color of `View`? Are you sure that i dont need a bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Radius parameter must be a float number, try to change it to 13f

```
drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint)

BitmapDrawable circle = (BitmapDrawable) canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2, (float) (canvas.getHeight()/1.8), 13f, black);
```

Comment: I actually get the error at the "Paint paint" parameter, the numbers should be right i guess, aren't they?

Comment: Try to type instead of black --> Color.BLACK

Comment: It needs to be as folow: Paint paint = new Paint();  paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

Comment: I'll edit the question with the complete code in a second

Comment: That is the code - i declared the color, but it says it cannot convert from void to bitmapDrawable